# codeigniter sessions set globally

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

I am trying to use codeigniter on authenticated pages and it prompts me to login every time ...I realized I could fix the issue with this

```
$lifetime=600;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
session_start();
```

Is there a way to make this universal on all the view pages without cutting and pasting on everypage or is there a better way to do this in codeigniter?

here is the [page](http://posnation.com/shopper)
username: abcd1234
password: english12

this will log u in as admin and then click on anything and you will see it prompts again for credentials

Comment: Are you not using the CodeIgniter session class?

Comment: i am ..here is my call $autoload['libraries'] = array('Authentication','session','database');

Comment: You don't use session_start() when you use CI session library. Check out http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the setting at the php.ini level with the `session.cookie_lifetime` setting, which'd make it globally applicable to all scripts:

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Comment: I dont have access to the php.ini in my host

Comment: How about .htaccess? You can put a `php_value session.cookie_lifetime XXX` directive in there, unless that's locked off too.